# iOS11 bluetooth has something strange

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios11

When I switch off the Bluetooth in setting, then I use `CBCentralManager` to get the state of the Bluetooth like this:

```
self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

the system will display a alert like this: [system alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y32Og.jpg)

The current state of Bluetooth is `CBManagerStatePoweredOff`. But when I switch off the Bluetooth in control center, this alert is not show anymore even if the current state of Bluetooth is still `CBManagerStatePoweredOff`.

How could I remind the user to switch on the Bluetooth in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can remind the users by implementing the following **delegate** method.

```
//Bluetooth state delegation
#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    NSString *stateString = nil;
    switch(self.CBManager.state)
    {
        case CBManagerStateResetting:
        stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent.";
        break;
        case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
        stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
        case CBManagerStateUnauthorized: stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
        break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
        stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
        break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
        [self.beaconManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.museumsRegion];
        [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion: self.museumsRegion];
        break;
        case CBManagerStateUnknown:
        stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent.";
        break;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", stateString);
}
```

Now the user should be informed automatically.

Comment: When you switch off Bluetooth in setting, this delegate method will be called , and system will display an alert by itself. When you switch off Bluetooth in control center, this delegate method will be called as well, but system will not display an alert. If remind the users in this method, maybe two alert will display in same time.

Comment: It could also be that you have to place now in the info plist the NSBluethoothInUse privacy key and set a string value. I thought I read something about this in iOS 11.

Comment: When the user switches off in the control center the Bluetooth state, you are able to monitor the state with the delegated method I showed above! So why not implementing a custom alert when you detect this state with your application code?

Comment: But when user switchs off in setting the Bluetooth state, I detect the state with the delegate you showed above.And then the system will display an alert, if I display in this method, there're two alert will be displayed in the same time in this situation. Do you get my point?

Comment: I got it. In my current app there is this situation aswell. Custom alert and system alert. It is not very comfortable but the only way to be sure you got this alert in any BLE state situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable system BlueTooth alert by using **CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey** in options dict.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @NO};
self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
```

Then you can using deleget method **centralManagerDidUpdateState:** to popup you custom alert.